# Get mobile number dial code of a android device in cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic world so please help me to get mobile number dial code (India +91) of a android device in ionic cordova project, you can suggest me cordova plugin also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim) should do what you need.

You can also write your own plugin if you need to, and use the `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` class in the Android SDK to query the device for its phone number.  If you do this, have a look at the `getLine1Number` and `getDeviceId` methods:

`String getDeviceId()`

> Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the  MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.
>
> Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE

`String getLine1Number ()`

> Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.
>
> Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE OR READ_SMS

Note that you will want a fallback method in case this can't be obtained, and for iOS devices should you port your application to iOS, as you cannot programmatically obtain the phone number from an iOS device any longer.

If you are looking for a general purpose tutorial on how to develop a plugin for Android (and iOS) then [my blog post on the topic](http://moduscreate.com/plugin-authoring-cordova-6-ios-android/) is a good place to start.